# Are dynamic routes in Next.js rendered server-side or client-side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working in a project that requires server-side rendering for SEO purposes, and I'm using Next.js and React, and I'm using [Next.js dynamic routing](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/clean-urls-with-dynamic-routing).

I created a simple page to check if it's working:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'

class Product extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Head />
        <h1>{this.props.router.query.name}</h1>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Product)
```

I place the code in `/pages/product/[name].js`, ran the dev server and visited `localhost:3000/product/cheese`.

When the page loaded, I checked the page source in my browser to check if it's rendered server-side, and nothing in the code contains the word `cheese`.

Am I doing it wrong? Is it rendered client-side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import Layout from '../components/MyLayout';
import Link from 'next/link';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';

const Index = props => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>Batman TV Shows</h1>
    <ul>
      {props.shows.map(show => (
        <li key={show.id}>
          <Link href="/p/[id]" as={`/p/${show.id}`}>
            <a>{show.name}</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </Layout>
);

Index.getInitialProps = async function() {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=batman');
  const data = await res.json();

  console.log(`Show data fetched. Count: ${data.length}`);

  return {
    shows: data.map(entry => entry.show)
  };
};
```

As you will soon see, you will need to use getInitialProps for it to be server side rendered.  Then this page will be created during the build, and will have all the applicable information in the view source.  Will have SEO as well.

When you run npm build, it will show you which is statically generated, and what is ssr.    But you need to use getInitialProps otherwise it will be generated client side.

Comment: hey thanks :) , I think I have to complete the tutorial first before writing some code. my bad...

Comment: All good, it can still be a tad bit confusing.  Just know getInitialProps = SSR.  Otherwise it will be client side generated (html is still generated statically, any dynamic content will be rendered on the client)